# How do I know if I have KMS enabled?

Tags: linux, graphics-card, amd-radeon, ati-mobility-radeon

How can I check if KMS is enabled in my kernel? I've compiled mine with KMS `radeon modeset` defaulting to `1`, but I still suspect that it is not enabled.

**`EDIT:`**

```
aatiis@aiur ~ $ dmesg | grep drm
[drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810
[drm] Initialized radeon 1.33.0 20080528 for 0000:01:05.0 on minor 0
[drm] Setting GART location based on new memory map
[drm] Loading RS780 CP Microcode
[drm] Resetting GPU
[drm] writeback test succeeded in 1 usecs
```

**`EDIT 2:`**

```
aatiis@aiur ~ $ glxinfo | grep render  
IRQ's not enabled, falling back to busy waits: 2 0
direct rendering: Yes
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI R600 (RS780 9612) 20090101  TCL

aatiis@aiur ~ $ sudo grep -i kms /var/log/Xorg.0.log
[    57.201] (II) [KMS] drm report modesetting isn't supported.
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

An easy test is this. Start an X session, then switch to a virtual terminal. If there's a slight delay, like the screen darkening for a second or so, KMS is NOT enabled. If it's near instant, it's almost certainly working.

Comment: is there any way to do it without X? I'm trying to install wayland

Comment: This isn't necessarily correct. While most drivers supporting KMS have implemented `fbdev`, which is what your test actually tests for, if you've got NVIDIA KMS setup, your test will fail despite KMS being enable.
KMS is not fbdev. If you've got `fbdev` you've got KMS, but it is not the case that without `fbdev` you do not have KMS.

Answer (score 2):

Kernel modesetting for radeon driver is supported after kernel version 2.6.31. If you have the driver with the version of later, you will be able to see a line that says "radeon kernel modesetting enabled." in dmesg log. Please check if dmesg contains any string with "modesetting."